# Is it possible to print a search pattern result just until it hits a blank newline in terminal?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, ag

Say for example I have a file with contents like this:

```
# TODO: Optimize this.
alias bash='start bash'

# FIXME: Just fix this.
alias fix='there is something wrong with this
```

What I want is if I search for pattern `TODO:` it should only print result like this:

```
# TODO: Optimize this.
alias bash='start bash'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can there be multiple TODO sections, and what should the output be in that case?

Comment: yes, there can be multiple match of the same pattern, in that case i want to only print the first hit if it possible with ambiguous search.

Answer (score 3):

Awk in *paragraph mode*:

```
awk -vRS= '/TODO:/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534306/how-can-i-set-the-grep-after-context-to-be-until-the-next-blank-line

but you'd need `sed` as suggested in the post:

`sed -n '/pattern/,/^$/p' file`

Answer (score -1):

`grep` solution.

```
grep -zoP '(?s)^# TODO.*^$' file
```